# In Python How to remove duplicates from a list/string using only for loop, if else statements and without using empty list, set function

Tags: drop-duplicates

I want to remove duplicates from a list by only using for and if else statements,
Without using set, enumerate functions, fromkeys and without using new empty array/list.
So in the given list, I wish to keep an item only if it appears one time, if it occurs to second time, I wish to delete the second appearance, third appearance

a = ['aa', 'bb', 'cc', 'aa', 'dd', 'ee', 'aa', 'cc', 'ff']

So here I wish to remove 'aa' on the 3rd index and 6th index and 'cc' on 7th index while keeping the rest list as it is.

Comment: In this, I was trying to get elements with len >= 2
----

abc = "asd dwasfd ersgf va s fas DAS AS SDG sd fg sdfg asd gsdgf"
----
abc = abc.split()
----
#print(abc)
----
for i in range(len(abc)): 
------
 if len(abc[i])<=2:
-----
  k = abc[i]
----
  #abc.remove(k)
----
  abc.append(k)
------
  #print(abc)
----
  
  for j in abc:
-----
   if len(j)>2:
-----
    abc.remove(j)
----
 #if count
----
 #if len(abc[i])<=2:
-----
  #abc.pop()
----
  #abc.append(abc[i]) 
-----
 #else:
-----
 #abc.remove(abc[0])
-----
 #del abc[abc.index(i)] 
------
print(abc)

Comment: and I have been able to print same elements twice
and was trying to use any if else or loop within the code to remove the item when it appears twice